# Why my class doesn't fill 100% of the screen?

Tags: html, css, meteor

I have the following script in my `html` file:

```
<template name="SideNav">
    <header>Lammah</header>
    <body>
        dd
    </body>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    </div>
</template>
```

And below is the `.css` file:

```
.nav {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #b7b7e5;  
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

a:hover{
  background-color: #A3A3CC;
}
```

When I run the html file, the `nav` class doesn't start from the beginning of the screen, there is small white space on the left as it is shown in the picture below:
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFQy2.png)

What is causing the `nav` class to not start from the beginning of the screen (bottom left)?

Comment: you have your `div` and `header` outside the `body`? this should not be.

Comment: @Luka I changed the `div` location inside `body` tag, but I got the same result unfortunately

Comment: Can you provide more context? Maybe a runnable snippet within the question? A picture can only help so much.

Comment: Structure your html in correct way: have `html` tag, inside it only allowed tags are `head` and `body`. Also, define your `template` in some allowed place, preferably somewhere inside `body`. Then if you have the same problem, edit the question

Comment: you are closing the `body` tag before the `.nav` div --> invalid HTML. Also, apply margin: 0 to `body` and `html` to reset the default margins.

Comment: @Johannes I added the following: `body{margin:0}` and put the `div` inside `body` tag and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> When I run the html file, the nav class doesn't start from the beginning of the screen, there is

This is because by default the `client/main.css` contains the following lines:

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

You should remove it in order to remove the white space.

**Furthermore some additions on your Template:**

The `head` and `body` should only be in your `client/main.html` while the body content will be rendered using the templates. This is, because Blaze is focused to develop single page applications.

So your code `client/main.html` may be like the following:

```html
 <header>
  <title>Lammah</title>
</header>

<body>
  {{> SideNav }}
</body>

<template name="SideNav">
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default margins and padding are still in place. What you will need is to make sure the parent element has margins and padding set to 0. So for example, the very first css element you will want to set based off  your above code would be this:

```
template {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using meteor technology and `template` is part of `blaze`, However, i tried your code it didn't work,

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 margin: 0 !important;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.